# ¿Por qué SimpleDateFormat acepta cadenas sin letras como un formato de fecha válido?

Tags: java, diseño

Esta pregunta la hago sobretodo para saber sobre decisiones de diseño al crear una librería o una api.

Me topé con [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391406/111110) y parece contraintuitivo para el diseño de la clase `SImpleDateFormat` porque va como sigue:

> No arrojaré una IllegalArgumentException Si el formato de fecha que me
>   das no tiene letras. Eso significa que aceptaré cualquier cadena con
>   símbolos basura y te la retornaré. Si el formato de fecha tiene al
>   menos una letra veré si es válido.

Yo esperaría que `SimpleDateFormat` arrojara una `IllegalArgumentException` cada vez que un formato de fecha inválido se le pasa a su constructor.
Este es mi código de ejemplo:

```
try
{
   String s = new SimpleDateFormat("34343434").format(new Date());
   System.out.println(s);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // no exception
}

try
{
   String s = new SimpleDateFormat("3434a3434").format(new Date());
   System.out.println(s);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // Exception, yay!
}
```

¿Por qué `Oracle/Sun` hizo esta decisión en el diseño de la clase `SimpleDateFormat`? Es un diseño que parece propenso a generar errores.

Lo que quisiera saber son las razones detrás de una dunción que se comporta de forma diferente a lo que se esperaeía de forma intuitiva (pensemos el caso de que se está codificando funciones para una librería que se quiere vender).

Una de las razones podría ser no añadir más complejidad a una función sólo para manejar escenarios que podrían no ocurrir, lo cual significa menor tiempo de entrega.

Comment: Esta pregunta, a pesar de ser concreta, parece un poco basada en opiniones y sería imposible poder contestarla tal cual si haber sido parte del equipo de Oracle/Sun que diseño esa clase. A no ser que haya un sitio donde se explique esa decisión, lo más que vas a obtener son conjeturas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tienes razón, como no podemos hablar con la gente de Oracle/Sun, hay mucho de suposición en las potenciales respuestas. En mi caso específico, me llamó la atención el comportamiento de esta función, tengo bastante flojo lo que es diseño de software y quise indagar un poco para poder aprender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que he podido rescatar de [la misma pregunta que hice en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44210378/111110).

- **Sí, es un mal diseño.** y sí, puede inyectar bugs en apps que usen la función o hacer más complejo el usarla de forma que no inyecte bugs (independientemente de si se leyó el manual o no).
- Ya dado suficiente tiempo, es mejor deprecar una función con funcionamiento "roto" o desactualizado. Es lo que está haciendo Oracle con Java.TIme.
- Ya desde el punto de vista del usuario, la mayoría de los códigos fuente de ejemplo mencionarán las funciones antiguas, sólo porque tienen más tiempo de uso. Esto no significa que sean las más recomendables.
- Específicamente la función SimpleDateFormat fue diseñada hace 20 años, la api actual de Java incluye mejores funciones en el manejo de fechas en Java.Time (la cual es un port del proyecto Joda).